# Context Free Grammar Equal Lengths

Tags: context-free-grammar

Consider the language L = {x#y is in {0,1}* where |x| = |y|}

Would this CFG be a sufficient definition of the language L?

S->0S0 | 0S1 | 1S0 | 1S1 | #

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.

Comment: I agree, looks fine to me.

Comment: Wait a minute! How can $x\# y$ be in $\{0,1\}^*$?  It contains a symbol $\#$ that is neither $0$ nor $1$.  Was the intention rather that $x$ and $y$ should be in $\{0,1\}^*$?  If so, then your grammar is OK.  If the definition of $L$ is taken literally, then $L$ is empty and an even simpler grammar works.

Comment: in definition of this language, must be written L={X#Y|X,Y $\in$ {0,1}* & |x|=|y|}

Answer (score 0):

No, from Definition of this language, we can generate '#0#1#' and in your grammar, we cant generate this.

First way: Change definition of language to:

$$L=\{X\#Y \mid X,Y\in\{0,1\}^* \& |X|=|Y| \}$$

Second way: Change grammar

$$S\rightarrow0S0|1S1|0S1|1S0|0S\#|\#S0|1S\#|\#S1$$

*Of course i think your goal is **First Way***